# Incomplete List Scrolling (ActionScript + Flex 4.5)

Tags: apache-flex, list, actionscript, scroll

I have a flex list, nothing fancy:

```
<s:List id="list" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" borderVisible="false"
    dataProvider="{data}" labelField="1" textAlign="left"
    itemRenderer="MXML.ItemRenderers.ListItemRenderer" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="left"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

The following ActionScript code snippets are used to automatically scroll to the bottom of the list when the content does not fit in the visible area. Note that only 1 of these code snippets is used at any given time, but they both have the same effect.

Snippet 1:

```
list.validateNow();
list.ensureIndexIsVisible(data.length-1);
```

Snippet 2:

```
list.validateNow();
list.layout.verticalScrollPosition += list.layout.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.END);
```

The problem is that these snippets do not scroll completely to the bottom of the list. To illustrate this, I have attached an image: the result on the list after the execution of the above snippets (they both give the same result).

[image: List Result]

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling to the bottom of a List can be tricky especially when renderers are of different heights, see this blog post for an example of how to accomplish this: http://flexponential.com/2011/02/13/scrolling-to-the-bottom-of-a-spark-list/